# Dynamic Sized Textbox between two static DIV's

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a textbox that spans the entire width of my middle column. Whenever I set the width of the textbox to 100% though it drops below the divs and doesnt look good. How do I keep the textbox contained in the middle DIV and have it be 100% of the middle DIV?

**HTML**

```
<div class="leftsidebar">a</div>
<div class="rightsidebar">b</div>
<div class="content">
  <div>
    <input type="text" style=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.leftsidebar { width: 60px; background:red; float:left; } 

.rightsidebar { background:blue; width: 170px; float:right; } 

.content { width: auto;background:yellow; }

.content input[type='text'] { width: 100%; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v0mp0wgm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). First, you want to create a containing div for your content, then assign it `display: flex;`. After that, move your `.content` div between the left and right sidebar and remove their floats. Then, give your `.content` and `.content input[type='text']` classes a width of `100%;` and you should be good to go.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.leftsidebar { width: 60px; background:red; } 

.rightsidebar { background:blue; width: 163px;} 

.content { width: auto; background:yellow; width: 100%; }

.content input[type='text'] { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftsidebar">a</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>
      <input type="text" style=""/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightsidebar">b</div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v0mp0wgm/3/)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to apply `float:left` to everything and use `calc()` :

```css
.leftsidebar {
float:left;
width: 60px;
background:red;
}

.content {
float:left;
width: calc(100% - 60px - 170px);
background:yellow;
}

.rightsidebar {
float:left;
width: 170px;
background:blue;
} 

.content input[type='text'] {
display: block;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftsidebar">a</div>

<div class="content">
<div>
<input type="text" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="rightsidebar">b</div>
```